# Launching video in custom player in from uiwebview

Tags: iphone, url, video-player

I want to launch video in custom video player when user click on clink in uiwebview in iphone. 
Currently video is played in the default as player as soon as link in clicked. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the [UIWebViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) and in particular the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

You can use that to intercept the click on the link. You will then need to determine if the request is for video or not. If it is for video, return NO from the method to prevent the UIWebview standard behaviour and instead, launch your own custom player.

Comment: It works for some video stream sites but for many such as dailymoition and metacafe  link click is not interceptable. if you click on link like: http://www.metacafe.com/watch/7657743/new_nook_colors_19_unlimited_wireless_and_verizons_holiday_plans_technobuffalo/ , link cannot be stoped from launching in default video player.